# Filtering an array of objects with a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React newbie here is asking for some help.
Here is the deal: I have an array of 4 objects (in my `Data.js` file) and, after clicking on a button, I want to display only the items belonging to "category A" in my example below. I'm a bit confused with the use of setState (which I assume I would need since my button will "update" the initial state to only reflect the data I want to display (hence item 1 and 4).
Any ideas how it can be done?
Cheers!

**index.js**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Data from "./Data.js";



class Root extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: Data,
        }
    }

myFunctionA = () => {
    // filtering in here
}
    
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.myFunctionA}>Click me to display item 1 & 4</button>
            </div>
            
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

**Data.js**

```
const Data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "First item",
    "category": "A"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Second item",
    "category": "B"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Third item",
    "category": "C"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Fourth item",
    "category": "A"
  },
]

export default Data
```

Comment: Try with `Data.filter((item) => [1, 4].includes(item.id))`

Comment: I guess it supposes that I know the place of every object in my array. Does it work if I don't know such info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you need to use setState.

Try something like that:

```
myFunctionA = () => {
    const filteredData = this.state.items.filter(elem => elem.category === 'A');
    this.setState({ items: filteredData });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! How would it works if I have a second button (let's say to filter for the category "B"), is there a way to do it without having to copy/paste the whole code and just replace A by B? I'm wondering in the case of, for example, 4 or 5 buttons (it would be messy to have several paragraphs almost identical. And last question, how would you do to display the result in the render() method? I got an error "Objects are not valid as a React child". But thank you very much, really helpful

Comment: You're welcome! For filtering other categories, you need to pass an argument to this function, i.e. `myFunctionA = category => {` and then replace `'A'` in function body with `category`. Then you can use it in separate functions like that: 
`filterByCategoryA = () => this.myFunctionA('A');` etc. For displaying this data in JSX you need to map through your data in render method, i.e. `{ this.state.items.map(el => <div> {el.name} </div>))}`. Remember that after first click you're modifying your state, so you'll need to store this data somewhere before filtering.

Comment: @AlexGlm did you achieve your goal?

Comment: Yes I already answered twice on my post to thank you for your help for none came through. But yes I managed, thanks to you!

Comment: @AlexGlm I saw both of your comments, seems like they disappeared

Comment: Hey Michal, sorry to come back to you that late. As you mentionned it, after my first click, my state has changed and is not my full database anymore. Is there an easy way to reset my state so that for the second click, it'll filter again within the full database? Thanks for your help on this

Comment: Hey, I'd suggest you making another property in `state` object to keep your filtered data in. Then you can use `items` property to store original data, and filter that data in i.e. `filteredData` property.

Comment: Something like that? https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-antonelli-l19ys
Sorry I understand more easily with some codeI can read

Comment: Something like that: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-sunset-8rc3z

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed it works very well with the short example I gave, still struggling with the real life case I'm facing but I'll try to manage. Thank you again :)